Reducing last Staff in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to reduce the size of last Staff in "UT QUEANT LAXIS" Gregorian Chant. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={2pt 7pt 192pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
%
\begin{document}%
\begin{music}%
\hsize=1.55\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ut que-ant la-xis re-so-ná-re fi-bris Mi-ra ges-tó-rum fá-mu-li tu-ó-rum, Sol-ve po-llú-ti lá-bi-i re-á-tum,
Sanc-te Jo-án-nes. Nún-ti-us cel-so vé-ni-ens Ol-ým-po, Te pa-tri mag-num fo-re nas-ci-tú-rum, No-men et vi-t{\ae} sé-ri-em ge-rén-d{\ae} Ór-di-ne pro-mit. Il-le pro-mís-si dú-bi-us su-pér-ni,
Pér-di-dit promp-t{\ae} mó-du-los lo-qué-l{\ae}: Sed re-for-más-ti gé-ni-tus pe-rémp-t{\ae} Ór-ga-na vo-cis. Ven-tris obs-trú-so ré-cum-bans cu-bí-li Sén-se-ras Re-gem thá-la-mo ma-nén-tem: Hinc pa-rens na-ti mé-ri-tis ut-ér-que Áb-di-ta pan-dit. Sit de-cus Pa-tri, ge-ni-t\'{\ae}-que Pro-li, Et ti-bi com-par u-tri-ús-que vir-tus, Spí-ri-tus sem-per, De-us u-nus, om-ni  Tém-po-ris {\ae}-vo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianFclef
%\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\sbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{d}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}% 
\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt{a}\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{Nab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%\hbsk% 
\squ{ba}\clivis{b}{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\torculus{a}{b}{a}\ptt{N}\ptt{a}\podatus{N}{a}\dsbrm\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is as follow:


Have you tried anything with \zstoppiece\hsize=(requested dimension)\startpiece? I can't guarantee that it works in standalone, but try the common way first.

Solved (thanks Peters):
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={2pt 7pt 192pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
%
\begin{document}%
\begin{music}%
\hsize=1.55\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ut que-ant la-xis re-so-ná-re fi-bris Mi-ra ges-tó-rum fá-mu-li tu-ó-rum, Sol-ve po-llú-ti lá-bi-i re-á-tum,
Sanc-te Jo-án-nes. Nún-ti-us cel-so vé-ni-ens Ol-ým-po, Te pa-tri mag-num fo-re nas-ci-tú-rum, No-men et vi-t{\ae} sé-ri-em ge-rén-d{\ae} Ór-di-ne pro-mit. Il-le pro-mís-si dú-bi-us su-pér-ni,
Pér-di-dit promp-t{\ae} mó-du-los lo-qué-l{\ae}: Sed re-for-más-ti gé-ni-tus pe-rémp-t{\ae} Ór-ga-na vo-cis. Ven-tris obs-trú-so ré-cum-bans cu-bí-li Sén-se-ras Re-gem thá-la-mo ma-nén-tem: Hinc pa-rens na-ti mé-ri-tis ut-ér-que Áb-di-ta pan-dit. Sit de-cus Pa-tri, ge-ni-t\'{\ae}-que Pro-li, Et ti-bi com-par u-tri-ús-que vir-tus, Spí-ri-tus sem-per, De-us u-nus, om-ni  Tém-po-ris {\ae}-vo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianFclef
%\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\sbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{d}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}% 
\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt{a}\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{Nab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%\hbsk% 
\squ{ba}\clivis{b}{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
%\zalaligne%
\zstoppiece\hsize=0.8\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\torculus{a}{b}{a}\ptt{N}\ptt{a}\podatus{N}{a}\dsbrm\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The output is as follow:

